# returning jquery alert box in function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, alert

i have written a javascript function and i want to return a message in the jquery alert box! currently the message is returned in a javascript alert box which seems not attractive for my program! i am  unfamiliar with jquery so please help me!

my program code is as follows and is used to identify whether an uploaded file is of image format or not! if its not an image format 1 an alert box is returned with an error message!(i want to make this alert a box a jquery 1) please help me

```
          var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];    
function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry a copy may be in a different file format! Formats allowed are " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to customise the size, colour, animations etc. of your alert box? If so, [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_dialog.htm) might be a start.

Comment: no the default jquery alert box

Comment: jquery is used for DOM manipulations. It does *not* have a "default jquery alert box".   The browser has an `alert()` which *cannot* be styled.   You can include jquery-ui and use a dialog or you can include any number of 100s of jquery or bootstrap dialog plugins or write your own.  Which is it that you are after?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>jQuery Alerts</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Example script -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready( function() {
     $("#basic_button").click( function() {
    jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    <input id="basic_button" type="button" value="Show Basic Alert" />
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can download the dependency files [here](http://www.tutorialscollection.com/download/jquery_alert_files.zip)

Comment: Simply use this JAlert() where you want to show message in alert box

Comment: i want it for my function

Comment: just replace alert() with JAlert()